# Cloned button can't open modal

Tags: javascript

The 2nd button that I cloned can't open the modal... how can I fix that?

[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/f7hjh1gf/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f7hjh1gf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass **true** in clone

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".myBtn").click(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal();
    });
    $("#mode").click(function(){
        $(".ok").clone(true).appendTo("#clones");
    });

});
```

Here is the link

https://jsfiddle.net/f7hjh1gf/1/

Comment: Thanks Brother it Works

Answer (score 1):

Use `clone(true)` according to the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".myBtn").click(function() {
    $("#myModal").modal();
  });
  $("#mode").click(function() {
    $(".ok").clone(true).appendTo("#clones");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <div class="ok" id="notok">
    <select>
         <option value="Male">Male</option>
            <option value="Female">Female</option>
        </select>
    <button type="button" class="myBtn" id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

  </div>

  <div id=clones></div>

  <button id="mode">Clone</button>




  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to delegate event

```
$("body").on('click', '.myBtn',function(){
    $("#myModal").modal();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".myBtn").click(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal();
    });
    $("#mode").click(function(){
        $(".ok").clone(true).appendTo("#clones");
    });

});
```